# matching values in dictionaries python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of tuples. The tuples contain a file name and a download url. 
I have imported these file names and download urls from a csv file and many of the file name, download url pairs are the same but some are not.

I need to add these tuples to a dictionary without making doubles of the filenames but making sure all unique download urls are collected. I was thinking the key could be the filename and the values would be a list of all the unique download urls for that file. I am still very new to python so I am having problems getting this done.

Given:

```
current_list = [('filename1', 'url1'), ('filename1', 'url2'), ('filename1', 'url3'), 
                ('filename2', 'url1'), ('filename2', 'url2'), ('filename2', 'url3')]
```

dictionary I need:

```
result = {'filename1' : ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'],
          'filename2' : ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Work on your problem until you have sample input, the desired output, and actual code you've put together trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the unique urls associated with each unique file, you can use a `dict`  of `set`s, where the keys of the `dict` are your file names and the values are `set`s of urls. Using a set ensures that only unique urls will be kept.

To make adding urls to the `dict` easier, you can use a `defaultdict`, which has default behavior when new keys are added. In this case, the default behavior should be to create an empty `set` to which the url will be added.

To add your data, loop through your list of (file, url) tuples, adding each url to the set of urls associated with the file.

```
from collections import defaultdict

current_list = [('file1', 'url1'), ('file1', 'url2'), ('file1', 'url3'), 
                ('file2', 'url4'), ('file2', 'url5'), ('file2', 'url6')]

result = defaultdict(set)

for file_name, url in current_list:
    result[file_name].add(url)

print result
# prints:
# defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'file2': set(['url5', 'url4', 'url6']), 'file1': set(['url1', 'url3', 'url2'])})
```

Once you've constructed the dictionary, you can process the contents by looping through the (key,value) pairs with `iteritems`, and work with the individual urls with an internal loop:

```
for file_name, url_set in result.iteritems():

    # do something with file_name here...
    print file_name

    # access urls like this:
    for url in url_set:
        print url
```

Comment: @shakfu Welcome to stack overflow! Glad I could help -- do you need any other assistance? If I've fully answered your question, you can "accept" the answer if you choose.

Comment: I do have one more question . I was hoping after adding all these urls to a dictionary  I would be able to use urllib to capture each url and download it separatley . dont even know where to begin on that . I'm thinking the module i would us is urllib but I cant seem to pull the string  'www.someurl.com/exename.exe' from the value set. I guess I would iterate throught the value set of each key with a for loop ? and pull the string individually ?

Comment: @shakfu I added some code to show how to access the items. That help?

Comment: Yes thank you very much .. for everything . I will try to stick to proper formatting when asking questions on here from now on .